# Cannot access PubMed or MEDLINE but can access other sites

Tags: google-chrome, firefox

I can not access [PubMed](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/m/pubmed/) or [MEDLINE](http://www.nlm.nih.gov/bsd/pmresources.html) (a top medical research website) in all my browsers (Chrome, Firefox and Internet Explorer) but I can access all other sites. Also I can access this same website in my Android phone and my wife's PC.

In Chrome it shows, `ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED` sometimes, please how do I resolve this?

Comment: have you tried rebooting your router and your PC?

Comment: What versions of  chrome / firefox?  also is async dns or  v8 Resolver in play on chrome ?  what OS ?

Comment: thank you Moab. I have done that already. I have also cleared disc space; checked my firewall settings

Comment: thank you linuxdev2013. versons of chrome/firefox are 43.0.2357.81/ 38.0.5 respectively. Pls how do I find out if async dns or v8 Resolver is in play on chrome? my OS is windows 8.1, 64-bit, 4GB RAM, i3-4005U CPU @ 1.70GHz.

Comment: thank you JakeGould, I'm using a 15" hp laptop 2013 edition with the OS specifications I gave to linuxdev2013 earlier, I just saw your answers. Thank you so much, let me use it right away; I'll notify you if it works. Thanks for being so kind (this issue has frustrated my literature search for my research work for sometime now)

Answer (score 2):

## ***Explanation :***

This is a DNS problem apparently your computer are not managing DNS as it should, also a firewall could cause that.

The solution would be modifying the DNS Server on your computer to set the DNS manually

## ***Solution :***

Use alternative DNS Like google DNS Server

```
8.8.8.8
8.8.4.4
```

## ***On Windows :***

> - Open Network Connections by clicking the Start button Picture of the Start button, and then clicking Control Panel. In the search box, type adapter, and then, under Network and Sharing Center, click View network connections.
> - Right-click the connection that you want to change, and then click Properties. Administrator permission required If you're prompted for an administrator password or confirmation, type the password or provide confirmation.
> - Click the Networking tab. Under This connection uses the following items, click either Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4) or Internet Protocol Version 6 (TCP/IPv6), and then click Properties.
> - To specify IPv4 IP address settings, do one of the following:
>
>   - To get IP settings automatically using DHCP, click Obtain an IP address automatically, and then click OK.
>   - To specify an IP address, click Use the following IP address, and then, in the IP address, Subnet mask, and Default gateway boxes, type the IP address settings.
> - To specify IPv6 IP address settings, do one of the following:
>
>   - To get IP settings automatically using DHCP, click Obtain an IPv6 address automatically, and then click OK.
>   - To specify an IP address, click Use the following IPv6 address, and then, in the IPv6 address, Subnet prefix length, and Default gateway boxes, type the IP address settings.
> - To specify DNS server address settings, do one of the following:
>
>   - To get a DNS server address automatically using DHCP, click Obtain DNS server address automatically, and then click OK.
>   - To specify a DNS server address, click Use the following DNS server addresses, and then, in the Preferred DNS server and Alternate DNS server boxes, type the addresses of the primary and secondary DNS servers.
> - To change advanced DNS, WINS, and IP settings, click Advanced.

[image: Capture 1] [image: Capture 2]

Comment: Good answer but user has said **Also I can access this same website in my android phone and my wife's pc**...its only his computer where he has problem. so probably not a router problem

Comment: aah i read "i can't" did not pay attention, thanks for the comment

Comment: yes sir. the problem is only in my pc

Comment: I have tried the above it still did not work, it now showed "This web page is not available ERR_NAME_RESOLUTION_FAILED". Thanks. Let me consider the 2nd option below

Comment: can you please keep google dns and run the command "netsh winsock reset" then reboot your computer

Comment: also run the command "ipconfig /flushdns"

Answer (score 0):

`ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED` tells me it could be a DNS issue in your computer.

To confirm this, try open the sites in question using their IP address.

If you are able to access them by IP address, i would suggest you to clear DNS Cache by following the steps below

1. Open command prompt as an Administrator
2. Run command **net stop dnscache**
3. Run this after that **net start dnscache**
4. Relaunch the browser and try to access the site

Comment: thanks. I could not access it using their IP address which is 130.14.29.110

Answer (score 0):

Both PubMed and MEDLINE are hosted on the NIH (National Institutes of Health) domain of `nih.gov`. So my guess would be that your PC might be having issues resolving that specific `.gov` hostname or even the .`gov` TLD (top level domain) itself.

I would recommend double-checking firewall settings and see if you can even ping `nih.gov` and perhaps check if you can do a traceroute to `nih.gov`.